# Handling different data types in while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, typeerror

I am using a sensor that provides float data. In case of a faulty measurement the sensor also sometimes returns a "None" value. I would like to collect the sensor data as long as it is in between a certain range:

```
def measure():
    
    data = np.array([[sensor[0], sensor[1], sensor[2]]])

    while sensor[0] > 0.0 and sensor[0] < 90.0
        
        data = np.append(data, [[sensor[0], sensor[1], sensor[2]]], axis=0)

    return data
```

As soon as the sensor returns a None value, an error comes up because the while command cannot handle different data types:

> TypeError: '>'not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'*

I tried to include a "is not None" condition in the while loop but with no success.
Can anybody help with an alternative approach or a workaround to this problem?

Comment: So the condition `while sensor[0] is not None and (sensor[0] > 0.0 and sensor[0] < 90.0):` returned the error? Its not clear where the error originated if you don't post the code that originated the error.

Comment: The full error message was: `while sensor[0] > 0.0 ans sensor[0] < 90.0: I used: `while (sensor[0] > 0.0 or sensor[0] is not None) and (sensor[0] < 90.0 or sensor[0] is not None):` because I do not want to interrupt the data collection (the while loop) in case of a "None" value.

Comment: Actually, this causes the same error message: `elif sensor[0] >= 0.0 and sensor[0] <= 90.0: Type Error: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I think you want to reconstruct your function and while loop as

```
def measure():
    while True: 
        if sensor[0] is None: 
            # Handle however you see fit
            pass
        elif sensor[0] > 0.0 and sensor[0] < 90.0: 
            data = np.append(data, [[sensor[0], sensor[1], sensor[2]]], axis=0)
        else: 
            break
    return data
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with this code the data collection is interrupted as soon as a "None" value is returned through the sensor. However, data collection should only end if the measured value of sensor[0] is exceeding the window of [0, 90]. None values should not cause any action.